# using declaration for public static const class members

Tags: c++, class, static, constants

Human defines many public static constants:

```
class Human
{
public:

static const int NUM_FINGERS = 10;
static const int NUM_TOES = 10;
static const int NUM_HANDS = 2;
static const int NUM_FEET = 2;

//The rest of the human class here
};
```

An unrelated class makes use of them frequently and has to qualify them with the class name:

```
class Unrelated
{
public:
int SomeFunction()
{
//Many uses of Human's public static constants
return Human::NUM_FINGERS + Human::NUM_TOES + Human::NUM_HANDS + Human::NUM_FEET;
}
};
```

In the case of a namespace you can:

```
using namespace blah;
```

Is there an equivalent for a sitaution like this?

```
using namespace Human; //wrong

int Unrelated::SomeFunction()
{
return NUM_FINGERS + NUM_TOES + NUM_HANDS + NUM_FEET;
}
```

Is it considered bad programming to define a bunch of constants that way?

Comment: Not all humans have 10 fingers, 10 toes, 2 hands and 2 feet.

Answer (score 2):

> An unrelated class makes use of them frequently and has to qualify them with the class name.

What's wrong with this? Think of it this way: What is a better variable name, `nt` or `num_toes`? Further qualifying the name with the class `Human` (or namespace `Human` if you change your class to a namespace) is a good thing, not a bad thing. It helps the compiler, it helps you as a coder from accidentally colliding with some other name, and it helps another human who is trying to understand your code.

Regarding the names `NUM_FINGERS`, etc: I recommend not using ALL_CAPS. Someday, someone will write a `NUM_FINGERS` macro that will turn your code into gibberish. Reserve ALL_CAPS names for macros, and then try to avoid macros.

Comment: Who is the random driveby downvoter? The recommendation to use ALL_CAPS for macros and macros only isn't just mine. You will find it in many, many coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Unrelated` is really `Unrelated_but_about_Humans`, you can simply say "I have the same constants as `Human`":

```
class Unrelated
{
private:
    static const int NUM_FINGERS = Human::NUM_FINGERS;
    static const int NUM_TOES = Human::NUM_TOES;
    static const int NUM_HANDS = Human::NUM_HANDS;
    static const int NUM_FEET = Human::_NUM_FEET;
}
```

(Other responses's remarks regarding fragilty, etc. still stand.)

Comment: I didn't think of that. I guess it really isn't Unrelated per se. It's related but it needs to be in its own class and it can't be a child class because the main class is the app object. There will be a total of 3 classes like this, so I would have to redefine the constants in all three. Maybe not worth it.

Comment: You could create a namespace called HumanConstants and put the constants there. Then have `Human` and the other classes import that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It depends somewhat on the situation.

The constants relate to the Human class, so it makes perfect sense that they are "owned" by it, and using the namespaced names (Human::NUM_ARMS) makes their usage unambiguous. (Imagine what would happen if you introduced new classes, like Octopus. You'd use Octopus::NUM_ARMS, which would be 8 rather than 2. Thank goodness for the localised class/namespace names!)

Of course, in the Human/Octopus situation you might want to reconsider using constants and instead use an Animal class/interface with a virtual GetNumArms() method that each can override. This would allow your client code to be only loosely coupled with Human and Octopus, and work well for both types of Animal. This would allow the underlying constants to be private to each of these classes.

Or if you are writing code in another direction, consider what the external class is calculating. Whose responsibility should this calculation be? Perhaps you should add the calculation to the Human class (e.g. `Human::GetNumLimbs()`, `Human::GetNumBodyParts()`)

Finally, we've all moved on from the 1970's, so I'd recommend using a more readable style for constants (e.g. `Human::cNumFeet` causes much less eye bleeding than `Human::NUM_FEET`, and won't be easily mistaken for any macros you have lying around)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's considered bad programming to flatten the namespaces, i.e. using `using namespace`, especially in the global scope. If it's a constant in the `X` class, write `X::constant`, otherwise you're just hindering the readability (and risk naming collisions).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it considered bad programming to define a bunch of constants that way?

Indeed it is, Your second unrelated class uses the constants from another class.This is an tightly coupled dependency. if first class gets modified for some reasons to remove/refactor the constants your second class gets affected too. Avoid such dependeny.